# Protocol buffer zero value for integer

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a Go struct what we are using currently in our restful API which looks like this:

```
type Req struct {
  Amount *int
}
```

I'm using pointer here, because if the Amount is nil, it means the `Amount` was not filled, if the Amount isn't nil, but it's zero, it means the field was filled, but the value is zero.

When we started to change to protofiles and we want to use it like, the main API get's the request as HTTP API and send it to the next service through gRPC with the same protofile I faced with the issue, the `proto3` can't generate pointer for the Amount. That's fine because the protocol buffers designed for the purpose of sending data between separated systems, but how can I handle the issue above, because if I get the request I can't decide that the Amount is nil or just zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update July 2023

The current Accepted answer is no longer true. `proto3` now supports the `optional` parameter which will generate a field with a pointer satisfying the original question. See https://protobuf.dev/reference/go/go-generated/#singular-scalar-proto3

For example:

```
message Foo {
   optional int32 bar = 1;
}
```

generates

```
type Foo struct {
   bar *int32
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`proto3` doesn't distinguish between zero and absent; the concepts of defaults and implicit vs explicit values disappeared:

- the default value is always zero (or false, etc)
- if the value is zero, it isn't sent; otherwise, it is

What you're after is more possible with `proto2`. Alternatively, just add a *separate* field to indicate that you have a value for something:

```proto
message Req {
    int amount = 1;
    bool amountHasValue = 2;
}
```

Or use a nested sub-message, i.e.

```proto
message Foo {
    Bar bar = 1;
}
message Bar {
    int amount = 1;
}
```

(so; without a value you *just* send a `Foo`; with a value, you send a `Foo` with a `Bar`, and whatever the `amount` is: it is)

Comment: Mostly it means we need proto2 for our use-case. Thanks